# Virus that scans hard drive for utility bill + ID?

Tags: malware, virus

Is it possible a virus or malware could scan a hard drive to find ID documents etc and upload them?

Randomly some old files were re-uploaded to Dropbox without any updates to them or modifications.

Did a virus intercept them somehow and only them?

Comment: Why would it upload them to your dropbox account?  Probably something touched the files (likely your antivirus) and this caused the dropbox software to think they had been modified.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to determine whether a virus has infected your files or not. Of course it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible a virus or malware could scan a hard drive to find ID documents etc and upload them?

If a virus or malware has infected your computer is can access any documents on its hard drives and possibly send them to somewhere. This of course includes any ID documents. Even should they be encrypted the virus can still access it, only then the recipient would not be able to make sense of them.

> Randomly some old files were re-uploaded to Dropbox without any updates to them or modifications.
>   Did a virus intercept them somehow and only them?

As explained above a virus that has infected your computer already has access to those files. Therefore there is no need to intercept them. Assuming however that your computer is not infected and you are only concerned about a possible "attack": Dropbox uses a secure connection and thus those files should not be leaked to the outside world in this way.

As to why Dropbox uploaded your files again, this question seems more appropriate to Dropbox or its users.

Comment: It is likely dropbox keep files "in sync", I don't have ti so I can't guarantee. A virus will likely to send files to a public visible place so they can get downloaded without letting the hacker be identified. If your dropbox folder is private than it is unlikely a virus